# Changing value of one column based on entries in another column using app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I'm a newbie in app script and want to automate the changes to a column based on the value of other 2 columns.

[image]

Columns B and C are regularly changed by the employees, if any of the columns have "Rejected" in them, the status of the candidate must change to Inactive.
I got the following code from a separate stack overflow question but due to my inexperience am facing issues in it.

```
    function myFunction3() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet8');
  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var columnNumberToWatch = 2; // column A = 1, B = 2, etc.
  //var values_needed = sheet.getRange("Sheet8!B2:N").getValues()
  var valueToWatch = 'Rejected';
  if (range.getColumn() == columnNumberToWatch && range.getValue() == valueToWatch) {
    range.offset(0, -1).setValue('Inactive');
  }
}
```

PS I cant use an array formula as I need to give ability to the employees to edit column A too

Answer (score 0):

Use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), like this:

```js
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) throw new Error('Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. ');
  let sheet;
  if (e.value !== 'Rejected'
    || e.range.columnStart < 2
    || e.range.columnStart > 3
    || !(sheet = e.range.getSheet()).getName().match(/^(Sheet8)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  sheet.getRange(`A${e.range.rowStart}`).setValue('Inactive');
}
```